# Wavelet Decomposition Query

Tags: matlab

I am new to wavelet and digital image processing .. 
I have written a small code for wavelet decomposition of my own face image , but it seems that there is some problem

```
X = imread('face.jpg');


[cA1,cH1,cV1,cD1] = dwt2(X,'db1');

i = [ cA1 cH1; cV1 cD1];
imshow(i)
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem here or if i am missing something .

Comment: Can you elaborate on what sort of problem you are experiencing? Is your code not running (as in, is it throwing an error), or is it running but not giving you the expected output? If it is throwing an error, it would be helpful to say what that error is. If it is not giving you the expected results, it helps to say what the results are, and how they differ from what you expect.

Comment: here is the documentation for `dwt2`... http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html

Comment: There is no error ... but the four images cA1, cH1, cV1, cD1 when i form a matrix of those the approximation that is the top left image is not showing properly ... it has just few dots ... i think i am missing  something

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this could be the problem, and here is a solution for it. Try using `wcodemat` to re-scale the matrix for display (shamelessly ripped of http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wcodemat.html):

```
load woman;
% Get the range of the colormap
NBCOL = size(map,1);
% Obtain the 2D dwt using the Haar wavelet
[cA1,cH1,cV1,cD1] = dwt2(X,'db1');
% Display without scaling
image(cA1);
colormap(map);
title('Unscaled Image');
figure;
% Display with scaling
image(wcodemat(cA1,NBCOL));
colormap(map);
title('Scaled Image');
```

Comment: load face.jpg;
% Get the range of the colormap
NBCOL = size(map,1);
% Obtain the 2D dwt using the Haar wavelet
[cA1,cH1,cV1,cD1] = dwt2(X,'db1');
% Display without scaling
image(cA1);
colormap(map);
title('Unscaled Image');
figure;
% Display with scaling
image(wcodemat(cA1,NBCOL));
colormap(map);
title('Scaled Image');

Comment: Error using image
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

Error in face_wavelet (line 7)
image(cA1);